# How to implement custom stateful metric in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to implement a custom stateful metric in Keras.  The Keras API [website](https://keras.io/api/metrics/) provides a short demo of how to do so.  However, the demo only includes `class` definition, creating an instance, and calculation of the metric from some data.  They do not demonstrate how to use it in the `model.fit` method, which is how I (and most people) would use it.  When I use it, I get results that (1) do not change epoch-to-epoch and (2) conflict with built-in metrics, so I know that I am getting incorrect results.  Am I using the code provided incorrectly or is the sample code not functional?

I am including a minimal demonstration of the issue below:

```
# libraries
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# setting psuedorandom seeds for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)
tf.random.set_seed(0)
random.seed(0)

# loads famous Iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x = iris.data
y = iris.target

# converts to binary prediction problem
y = np.where(y == 2, 1, 0)

# train/validation split 
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2)

# reformatting 
x_train = tf.constant(x_train)
x_val = tf.constant(x_val)
y_train = tf.constant(y_train)
y_val = tf.constant(y_val)

# stateful metric code from keras website
class BinaryTruePositives(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='binary_true_positives', **kwargs):
        super(BinaryTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)

        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, self.dtype)
            values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        self.true_positives.assign(0)

# demonstration from website (correct value is returned)
m = BinaryTruePositives()
m.update_state([0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0])
print(m.result())

# instantiates metric
true_pos = BinaryTruePositives()

# defines a very simple model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# compiles model
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['Recall', true_pos])

# trains model and prints output
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    epochs = 30,
                    verbose = 1,
                    validation_data = (x_val, y_val),
                    batch_size = 10
                    )
```

Notice that recall improves, while true positives remains constant, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified your `BinaryTruePositives` class, because in your model, y_pred is a continuous variable in (0, 1), not boolean. You need to convert it to a boolean variable using tf.where(y_pred > 0.5, True, False) for example.

```
class BinaryTruePositives(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='binary_true_positives', **kwargs):
        super(BinaryTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
        y_pred = tf.where(y_pred > 0.5, True, False)

        values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
        values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, self.dtype)
            values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        self.true_positives.assign(0)
```